# Use a variable for a field value in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to query the following:

```
Programs.find({ Teachers: { Week1: { Sunday: $elemMatch: { $eq: "MATT EDWARDS"}}}}).count();
```

...but the field "Week1" needs to be a dynamic value; it's depending on a variable's value. The variable is:

```
var week = "Week" + Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
```

A direct substitution won't work:

```
Programs.find({ Teachers: { week: { Sunday: $elemMatch: { $eq: "MATT EDWARDS"}}}}).count();
```

I'm not sure how to build the object to it can be read inside the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just building an object to pass to Programs.find(). You can utilize the fact that

```
object.property
```

is shorthand for

```
object["property"]
```

You can use a variable instead of a string literal, allowing you to accomplish your goal with:

```
var query = { Teachers: {} };
var week = "Week" + Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
query.Teachers[week] = { Sunday: $elemMatch: { $eq: "MATT EDWARDS" } };

Programs.find(query).count();
```